# Is constructing and passing an array/other container in function call possible?

Tags: c++, parameter-passing

Is there any way to construct an array of strings inside a function call?  For example, say I have a function like this:

```
void foo( char * [] strings )
{
    //...does stuff
}
```

And instead of declaring the character array first and then passing it, is there any way, with arrays or any other container class, to call the function like this?

```
foo( { "a", "b", "c", ...} );
```

Basically I have a function that prompts a user for input until it matches one of the strings in the array I pass, and since that changes throughout the program, I pass the accepted inputs into the function that prompts the user and validates the input.  Currently I am just constructing it outside the function and passing it in but was wondering if they could be combined into one line in any way

Comment: Is there a specific language we're looking at here? I mean it looks like C or C++, but a clarification would help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in C99:

```
void fun(char *argv[])
{
    while(*argv)
        printf("%s\n", *argv++);
}

fun((char*[]){"aaa", "bbb", NULL});
```

Since you mention "container" you probably use `C++` so this answer is of limited value (unless you are using a compiler that accepts it as an extension - the way GCC does for example).

Comment: Hey hey, that worked!!  So is that a type cast?  And I take it the NULL is necessary since memory has not been set aside for it so there is no way for the function to know its size?

Comment: It's a compound literal. You're right about the NULL part. It's not necessary, just convenient.

Comment: Very cool thank you.  I am getting input from the user and checking if that is an acceptable input, but what is acceptable changes from one part of the program to another.  So I wrote a function to do it but was having to construct a char*[], then copy it into a vector<string>, and you know how messy and ugly that is, especially when it happens over and over again for different inputs!  This is going to make my code a whole lot cleaner and readable thanks!!!

Comment: OK so I added that into my program and as long as the input matches one of the strings I pass in, everything is fine, but if I enter something that does not, I get a bus error and program termination!  Any ideas?

Comment: oh, except all my function were declared as `const char*[]` so I did `(const char * []){"q", "c", NULL }` for example

Comment: well it looks like it has something to do with accessing something that isn't there.  Instead of the `while(*argv)` I did `int i = 0` and `while(`i < 2 )` and it didn't crash until the second time the function was called and when I put 1 it doesn't crash at all.  Should be something easy to fix I hope!!!

Comment: OK got it!!!  Just changed `while(*argv)` to `while(argv[count] != NULL)` and initialized count to 0 and iterated each loop.

Comment: @Blake I was away. Good job debugging it.